# javascript regular expression matching help

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex that matches the "()" one time in:

```
hello()
hello(asd, 2)
hello(asd,sad))
```

That is, the 1st and the 2nd one should match but not the 3rd one.

Also the () has to be at the end so:

```
hello(asd)q
hello(asd)-
```

wont match.

In other words I want the regex to help me know if the string is a valid function call so i can use eval() on it.
Could someone help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `eval`?  You could avoid using it entirely and it's especially easy if the functions you're calling and arguments you're passing are in the global scope or just primitives.

Comment: I want to let the user enter in a textfield hello("peter") and it will get called. Eval is the only way here.

Comment: it's not true that `eval` is the only way, but I won't press the argument since it's not really a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it

```
/(^|\s+)\w+\([^)]?\)$/
```

Or if the function call is the only code in the string

```
/^\s*\w+\([^)]?\)$/
```

Comment: You probably want a `^` at the beginning too.

Comment: Good point - or maybe a (^|\s+) to allow for function calls not taking up the whole line